# How can I disable UFW logging for a specific event?

Tags: logs, firewall, router, syslog, ufw

[My router sends out multicast packets in regular intervals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278964/what-could-be-the-cause-for-these-strange-ufw-block-entries-in-my-syslog) that are blocked by UFW's standard policies. These events are harmless but spam my `syslogs` and `ufwlogs`. I can't change the router's behaviour as that would require installing a modified firmware and thus void the warranty.

So my question is: Is there any way I can prevent UFW from logging this particular event without changing the blocking policies? And, as a possible follow-up: If I can't define a custom logging policy, would allowing this incoming traffic pose a possible security risk?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Base on this [answer from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/453723/in-ufw-is-there-any-way-to-disable-logging-for-a-particular-rule),

> ufw supports per rule logging. By default, no logging is performed when a packet matches a rule.

All you have to do is create a UFW deny rule to match those multicast packets.

Comment: Well, that was much easier than I thought it would be. Dropped a simple `sudo ufw deny from SRC=192.168.178.1 to 224.0.0.1` and the log entries are gone. Thank you very much!

Comment: `sudo ufw deny from 192.168.178.1 to 224.0.0.1` worked for me (ufw ver. 0.31.1-2)